# const_cast in template. Is there a unconst modifier?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, const-cast

I have a template class like this:

```
template<T>
class MyClass
{
  T* data;
}
```

Sometimes, I want to use the class with a constant type T as follows:

```
MyClass<const MyObject> mci;
```

but I want to modify the data using `const_cast<MyObject*>data` (it is not important why but `MyClass` is a reference count smart pointer class which keeps the reference count in the data itself. `MyObject` is derived from some type which contains the count.
The data should not be modified but the count must be modified by the smart pointer.).

Is there a way to remove const-ness from `T`? Fictional code:

```
const_cast<unconst T>(data)
```

?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way here would be to make the reference count mutable.

However, if you are interested in how it would work with the `const_cast`, then reimplementing boost's `remove_const` should be quite simple:

```
template <class T>
struct RemoveConst
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct RemoveConst<const T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

const_cast<typename RemoveConst<T>::type*>(t)->inc();
```

Comment: @danatel: You really don't want to use remove_const. Modifying a const value by casting away constness is undefined behavior. You want to use __mutable__ on the refcount variable.

Comment: :-) I do use mutable. I didn't need a solution to my problem, the problem was there just as an illustration (please read the original post) - I was  curious if there is a way to remove constantness.

Answer (score 7):

You have the answer. const_cast works in both directions:

```
char* a;
const char* b;

a = const_cast<char*>(b);
b = const_cast<const char*>(a); // not strictly necessarily, just here for illustration
```

As for you specific issue, have you considered the mutable keyword? It allows a member variable to be modified inside a const method.

```
class foo {
    mutable int x;
public:
    inc_when_const() const { ++x; }
    dec_when_const() const { --x; }
};
```

Comment: But this is a template class. T is const something. The question is: how do I create nonconst something from T?

Answer (score 4):

Make the reference count mutable in the class managed by your intrusive pointer. This is entirely reasonable, and reflects "logical constness" exactly correctly -- i.e. changing the object's reference count does not reflect any change in the state of the object itself. In other words, the reference count isn't logically part of the object -- the object just happens to be a convenient place to store this semi-unrelated data.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Boost, the Type Traits library provides the [remove_const](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_const.html) metafunction that does that.

Comment: Unfortunately, on this project I cannot use Boost. But if there had been an easy way to do this in standard C++ then nobody would  write remove_const. Therefore there is no such way.

Comment: Did you read the other answers? Boost is just a meta-templated version, just use const_cast and remove const from it or mutable, like jumcchellio said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my C++11 `unconst` function `template`.

If you use it, you are flirting with **[undefined behavior](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=c%2B%2B%20undefined%20behavior)**.  You have been **warned**.

```
// on Ubuntu (and probably others) compile and test with                                                        
//   g++ -std=c++11 test.c  &&  ./a.out  ;  echo $?                             

template < class T >  T &  unconst  ( T const & t ) {
  return  const_cast < T & >  ( t ) ; 
}

// demonstration of use

struct {
  const int n = 4;
} s;

int main () {
  unconst ( s.n ) = 5;
  return s.n;
}
```

Comment: I think this would be simpler and has the same effect: `template<class T> T& unconst(T const& t){return const_cast<T&>(t);}`.

Comment: Thanks!  It is simpler and seems to work.  I wondered what the difference was between `typename` and `class`.